# Django unable to get models module

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning Django and not sure what is causing the error '**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'**'

even though the files are in the same folder
files are available [here](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0V8QsjS2hPHHkEsqT9i1B1GLA#app-7-django)

```
  File "/Users/mayanksharma/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/for Stackoverflow/app-7-django/blogs/urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/mayanksharma/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/for Stackoverflow/app-7-django/blogs/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from models import Post
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by?

```
from .models import Post
```

Replace `from . import views` with:

```
import sys
sys.append('..')
import views
```

Comment: Yes not sure why it does not work plus ***from . import views*** is also not working

Comment: @Myk1709 Please show us an example directory file order

Comment: blogs/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    migrations/
        __init__.py
        0001_initial.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py

mysite/
    __init__.py
    asgi.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py

templates/
    blog.html

manage.py
db.sqlite3

Comment: same issue :( 
should I share the whole error in the console may be you can find something.

Comment: @Myk1709 Ok. That would help

Comment: Hi i have added the error in text file here --> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FWMOVhXIBPAF9ubuDL5Dfuu0NMyU9iFC?usp=sharing
as stackoverflow won't allow me to add that much text

Comment: @Myk1709 I don't have apple :(

Comment: just updated google drive link sorry about that

Comment: @Myk1709 Which code are you running to get the error?

Comment: I am running `python3 manage.py runserver` command

Answer (score 0):

This was something to do with python reading path instead of from `.models import Post` or `from . import views` I gave `from app.models import Post` and that made it work